# javafx customized event: event class, fire event, and event handler?

Tags: event-handling, javafx-2

The usage case is that: heavy load task is usually scheduled on separate thread. And after task done, that thread will fire an event( even containing returned result), then main&other  thread will capture the event and do other actions.

Question is: how to achieve this in Javafx? how to define customized event (not UI event), and fire it from one thread, capture from other thread?

I googled around, but don't find a concrete method. Can some one help? thanks.

Comment: JavaFX task sounds similar ..http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Comment: Task/Service is a way to schedule non-ui jobs to background thread. The thing i'm looking for is ad-hoc event operation. Thanks for your information.

Comment: ah sorry i didn't understand your question before :(